# MySQL LIKE/Full String Check

Tags: mysql

I have a table where i save some User Agents like Mozilla, Google Chrome, Opera etc etc
The strucure is the following

```
[ id , user_agent , exact_match ]
```

I want to block any user if he uses one of the user agent that it is blocked in my table but also count the value of exact_match.

For example, if I  set the exact_match to be 1 `(TRUE)`,I want to perform full string check against the user agent, but if I set to 0 `(FALSE)`,I want to use LIKE in the mysql query.

I can do that easily if I SELECT ALL the user agents and depending on the exact_match, I can perform stristr function or just strcmp.

Can this be done using just one sql query and not PHP code?

**EDIT**:
All the checks should be done with case insensitive search.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a lot easier than you might think.

```
SELECT id, user_agent, exact_match
FROM table
WHERE (exact_match = 1 AND user_agent = :USER_AGENT_EXACT)
OR (exact_match = 0 AND user_agent LIKE :USER_AGENT_LIKE)
```

Then just prepare your statement then bind `USER_AGENT_EXACT` and `USER_AGENT_LIKE` with the strings required and away you go!

Comment: oh god. Why i dont think well before write :D You are right. Damn it